# English translation of Kellerer (1964)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, marginal-distribution

I am wondering if there is an english translation of Kellerer's 1964 paper on existence of joint distributions with particular marginals. The german version is here: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01360315.pdf

Any reference perhaps to a restatement of the result in english or french would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a version of the main result, including an alternative proof, as Theorem 6 of

> Strassen, Volker. "[The existence of probability measures with given
> marginals.](https://doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177700153)" *The Annals of Mathematical Statistics* 36.2 (1965):
> 423-439.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of Strassen's (brilliant) paper. However, Strassen claims that his Theorem 7 does not hold generally for indicator functions when we consider cartesian products of 3 or more spaces - his theorem 11 is that statement for Cartesian product of two spaces. He mentions Kellerer and I wanted to see if Kellerer somehow deals with this.

Comment: I'll take a look. The  notation of Kellerer makes it difficul to read even for German speakers.

Comment: Thanks a lot; I appreciate it. Just to give you a sense of what I am thinking, , in many application of Strassen's theorem that I have seen, often only indicator functions are used. The conditions become a lot easier to check. Perhaps an indicator version of Strassen's result exists somewhere (not necessarily in Kellerer); maybe I should just post it as a separate question!

Comment: @Ali Can you specify which theorem in Strassen's paper you mean? Theorem 6 is about indicator functions (=measures of measurable sets).

Comment: I am talking about Theorem 11. Thm 11 can be thought of as a special case of Thm 7 when functions $y$ and $z$ are restricted to be indicator functions $\mathbf{1}_U$ and $\mathbf{1}_V$. You are correct about Thm 6 though but that one is limited to joint measures dominated by a specific measure and even then it does not state whether it can be generalized for Cartesian products of more than two spaces.

Comment: I might have overseen something, but I did not see any result that does this in Kellerer's paper either.

Comment: I see thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe this comes close to what you are looking for: [https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176989396](https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176989396)